# The tag 'XamlControlsResources' does not exist in XML namespace 'using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls'

Tags: wpf, xaml, winui

I was trying to use WinUI so I installed the plugin Microsoft.UI.Xaml (2.4.2) from Nuget
and followed the instructions which says add This `<XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"/>` to my App.Xaml

and here is my App.Xaml file

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
        <Application.Resources>
            <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
        </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

but it says:

> The tag
> 'XamlControlsResources' does not exist in XML namespace
> 'using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls'

i tried older versions from WinUI plugin and tried .Net Core and Framework but still having this problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this WinUI 2.4.2 library is only compatible if you create a UWP application, not a WPF app.

[image]

Having said that, according to [this documentation from Microsoft](https://microsoft.github.io/microsoft-ui-xaml/about.html), starting with WinUI 3, you will be able to do this in WPF.

[image]

Comment: yea you are right, i was going to delete my question after reading those documents but found out that you answered me already so i accepted the question and im gonna keep it, thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<package id="Microsoft.UI.Xaml" version="2.5.0-prerelease.200812001" targetFramework="native" />
```

If you browse and can't find it add a line containing the above to the packages.config file check installed and the wait for Restore to show up in Nuget tools.

Make certain a reference is in the `<Import Project="packages\Microsoft.UI.Xaml" version="2.5.0-prerelease.200812001..."`

And also the `<Error Condition="!Exists('packages\Microsoft.UI.Xaml" version="2.5.0-prerelease.200812001..."` 
in the .vcxproj file for your project.

Comment: actually i was supposed to use UWP but i didnt know that at first, i was using WPF thats why it wasn't working, but thanks anyways